# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to solve a crossword puzzle and one method is to put a word in the puzzle.
But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
at CrosswordPuzzleSolver.setWord(CrosswordPuzzleSolver.java:224)
```

This is my code:

```
  public static char[][] setWord(int[] gridSpecEntry, String wordsSpecEntry,
        char[][] grid) {
        if (wordsSpecEntry.length()>0&&wordsSpecEntry.length()==gridSpecEntry[2])
        {
        int y = gridSpecEntry[0]; //y-coordinate
        int x = gridSpecEntry[1]; //x-coord
        int w = gridSpecEntry[2]; //length of word
        int r = gridSpecEntry[3]; //horizontal or vertical
        if (r == 0) { //if is 0, you need to put in the word horizontal
            for (int b = 0; b < wordsSpecEntry.length(); b++) {
                grid[y][x + b] = wordsSpecEntry.charAt(b); //line 224
            }
        } else {
            for (int a = 0; a < wordsSpecEntry.length(); a++) {
                grid[y + a][x] = wordsSpecEntry.charAt(a);
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `x+b` and `y+a` is probably your issue.

Comment: For which input does this produce this error?

Comment: it produces the error for SCHWIMMBAD

Comment: What's the input for gridSpecEntry?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your grid variable is smaller than your string.

I haven't tested at a workspace yet but try:

```
for (int b = 0; b < wordsSpecEntry.length() && x+b < grid[y].length(); b++)
```